# Chrome won't start from the launcher

Tags: 13.10, launcher, google-chrome

I have Ubuntu 13.10 64-bit and chrome 64-bit.

I can start chrome from the command line with `google-chrome-stable` and lock it to the launcher, but when I try to launch chrome from the launcher nothing happens.

What do I have to do to make chrome working with the launcher?

Comment: I copied the file `/usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop` to my Desktop and I can launch it from there.  It still doesn't work from the Launcher, however.

Comment: I have this issue too. Hope someone can figure this out.

Comment: Still have this issue with Ubuntu 14.0* and Chrome 38

Answer (score 29):

You probably have an old version, or a version with an error, of the `.desktop` file in `~/.local/share/applications`. The "reading priority" of the launcher is:

1. the local directory for desktop files in in `~/.local/share/applications`,
2. the global directory for desktop files in `/usr/share/applications`.

That means that if you start the application from the "right" (global) `.desktop` file, the launcher will check for a local version of the `.desktop` file on the next occasion and use the contents of that file.

You will have to remove the local `.desktop` file, log out and in, and lock the icon to the launcher again.

Comment: That solved it! Great! When using `Super` and searching for `chrome`, it finds two. One is called "Chrome - Google Chrome" and one is just called "Google Chrome". The former one does not work, and its what was linked against the launcher for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem was that the local launcher definition (`~/.local/share/applications/google-chrome-stable.desktop`) was pointing to the wrong path for the chrome executable. Using `whereis google-chrome-stable` I replaced to the right path, then started `google-chrome-stable &` from terminal, locked to the launcher, voila.

Answer (score -2):

Your Chrome window may be off screen. Try checking your workspace settings.

To see that the process is still there.

In the terminal type:

```
ps ax | grep -i chrome
```

In the terminal type:

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/ 
unity --reset-icons &disown
```

If the window still is not showing up, you may need to reboot the system so the changes apply.

Comment: Why would this be happening? Do you know?

Comment: Nope. The icon is blinking for a while, then stops blinking. Chrome has never started.