# google chrome launcher isn't working

Tags: unity, launcher, google-chrome

I just downloaded google chrome from official site of chrome, and installed it. 
Now I locked it to the launcher. There is an Icon of google chrome. But when I click on it, nothing opnes. I always have to search in the dash and then have to open from the search results. 
I want it to open from launcher as other programs do. 
any solution for this?

Comment: see if it is this problem: http://askubuntu.com/a/437073/72216, it probably is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above mentioned commands by @Smoke didn't worked, but they just started installing the google chrome again.
The real solution to this problem was mentioned in this question's answer... [Chrome won't start from the launcher](https://askubuntu.com/questions/418295/chrome-wont-start-from-the-launcher/437073#437073)

Answer (score 0):

Open up your Terminal(Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)
And Paste this Command in it

```
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb
```

Press enter after pasting this code.
After that code completed processing, Paste this code and press enter !

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

i hope its works!!  :)

Comment: Can you please explain what these commands are supposed to do?

Comment: @Smoke he already has chrome installed, his launcher link just isnt working...

Comment: it just started installing chrome :( now let's see if the second command works or not >:O

Comment: this is not a proper answer you are just suggesting him to reinstall