# Irrelevant tool tip text displayed in launcher for chrome

Tags: launcher, google-chrome, tooltip

When i open any page on chrome and wrong tool tip text is displayed for it (tool tip text of a page i opened some time before) in the launcher. How do i get rid of this.
I use ubuntu 14.04 32bit.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is not the same. nor the symptoms, but it is related to [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/418295/chrome-wont-start-from-the-launcher) and [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/516207/how-to-remove-duplicate-entries-in-dash/516346#516346).

#### What is the issue

It looks like your global `.desktop` file in `/usr/share/applications`, representing the locked icon in the launcher (the topmost one in your image), has a differently named copy in `~/.local/share/applications` . Maybe (likely) as a result of using webapps in the past. When you run the application from the locked launcher icon, the local version of the (differently named) `.desktop` file shows up as a second icon in the launcher.

Looking at your image, that seems to be the case.

*Note: if you open the local version of the `.desktop` file (drag it over a `gedit` window), you will probably find your strange tooltip in the line starting with `Name=`.*

#### What you need to do

Look into `~/.local/share/applications` (hidden by default, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to make it visible) and find `.desktop` files that might be calling `chrome`. If you doubt a file, make the file executable. Its icon will show up on the file then, so you will be able to recognize it by its icon. Remove any `.desktop` file, calling Google Chrome, from the directory `~/.local/share/applications`.

When an application is started from an icon, locked to the launcher, and a second icon appears *showing a correct icon*, it is practically always caused by a duplicate `.desktop` file with a different name, but calling the same application.

Comment: I just found the .desktop file that calls Google Chrome and edited its name attribute by calling `gedit google-chrome-stable.desktop` and restarted chrome it worked.