# Chrome broken unity launcher

Tags: unity, launcher, google-chrome, unity-dash

I'm having problems with the Chrome launcher icon for Ubuntu 14.04.

When I open Chrome for the first time, both via the icon launcher (call it icon1) that through any other way, it creates a new icon (call it icon2) in the Launcher; the default behavior, as you already know, should be to modify the clicked icon with a new background and an arrow on the left. 
Then, if I move the mouse on icon2, it always display the same title (focus@will - google chrome) even if this page is not open in any chrome window.

[image: Launcher title]

Also, I can't use icon2 to open a new window because there is no such option; so if I leave only icon2 as the locked launcher icon, I'm unable to launch Chrome at all.
Finally, when I type chrome in the dash, I have three different result.
[image: Dash]
This problem seems to be related to the last update (not too sure btw).
I already tried to remove Chrome (without purge), but nothing changes.

Comment: Chrome is famous for its behaviour on `.desktop` files. You must have outdated/incorrect `Chrome` `.desktop` files in `~/.local/share/applications`, see http://askubuntu.com/a/516346/72216 and http://askubuntu.com/a/437073/72216

Comment: Ty @JacobVlijm for your help. Indeed, this is the files chrome-related in the folder http://pastebin.com/rtgtPJky
Should I delete all of them?

Comment: Ok, it seems that the two files involved are `chrome.desktop` and `google-chrome-stable.desktop`: both have the same `Exec` but different `Name`.